# How to swipe UIScrollView after longPress without lifting finger?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer

I'm working on a UIScrollView that has scrollEnabled == false as initial setting. And by long-pressing the view, scrollEnabled = true. It works fine but users have to lift the finger to trigger the swipe. I'm thinking about long-press and swipe afterwards without the need to lifting finger. But I have not found a solution yet. (I tried googling, no luck so far.)

I'm using UILongPressGestureRecognizer for the long press and nothing else.

Thanks for your help in advance,

Liwei

Comment: You need to make a custom gesture for that I believe.

Comment: @Arbitur Thanks for your advice. I'll take a look at how to do it.